# Why I saw "see tombstone_warn_threshold" in cassandra, even I did not delete anything?

Tags: cassandra

When I do a table scan like "select*from ..",I saw a lot of warns like following. However I did not delete anything. It is also weird that the delInfo does not make sense to me, the deletedAt timestamp was event eariler than when I created the table.

ned cells in yp_rtb.bidresponses (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 1001 columns was requested, slices=[-], delInfo={deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=2147483647}
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-17] 2015-04-21 14:46:23,473 SliceQueryFilter.java:242 - Read 1002 live and 2657 tombst

Comment: Do you set TTLs on your data?

Comment: No I did not set TTL when I inserted data. And table's default_time_to_live = 0.

Comment: You can use sstable2json to find what was tombstoned and when it happened which may help you narrow down where they are coming from

Comment: Did you insert nulls? Those are written as tombstones. That delInfo is the row delete - it means that there is no row delete since deletedAt=-Long.MAX_VALUE and localDeletion=Integer.MAX_VALUE.